# What does "except for Islamic laws" mean in Sahih al-Bukhari 25?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith

[Sahih al-Bukhari 25:](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/18)

> **Narrated Ibn 'Umar:**
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: "I have been ordered (by Allah) to fight
> against the people until they testify that none has the right to be
> worshipped but Allah and that Muhammad is Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), and
> offer the prayers perfectly and give the obligatory charity, so if
> they perform that, then they save their lives and property from me
> **except for Islamic laws** and then their reckoning (accounts) will be done by Allah."

**What does "except for Islamic laws" mean?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is that a Muslim may be legally killed as punishment for breaking some laws. A list of these may be found here: [Why do Muslims kill other Muslims?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56206/why-do-muslims-kill-other-muslim)

Comment: Thank you. The other post of yours you gave reference to is also interesting. Jazakallahu Hairun